# Is category theory just type theory with different words?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

According this [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory#idea) category theory provides a semantics for type theory. To me this means that category theory and type theory are essentially the same system just with different words.

In fact this seems to mean there is an isomorphism between type theories and category theories.

Just change the word 'type' to 'category'.

Thus if type theory and category theory have converged on the same mathematical and grammatical structure, what is the point of keeping the two systems. Shouldn't the mathematical community just get rid of either type theory or category theory and just keep one of them?

Comment: Type theory is one of many categories. There are many other categories.

Comment: There are also many type theories. And since type theory can encode all mathematics, shouldn't it also encode all categories? If they both can be used as a basis for mathematics, aren't they in the end equivalent?

Comment: Since set theory can encode all mathematics, aren't set theory and type theory in the end equivalent? (My point is that there are meaningful differences between mathematical systems with the same "expressive strength.")

Comment: @Noah Well no because Set Theory doesn't encode logic, for example, while type theory can.

Comment: @zooby "Set Theory doesn't encode logic" Not sure what that means. More broadly, you need to define what you mean by "encode" (and "isomorphism" in the OP).

Comment: @Noah Set theory is built on the logical axioms. But type theory you can define the logical axioms using type theory.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're getting at. Can you precisely define "encode logic" for me? Under any interpretation I can think of, set theory absolutely can encode logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I believe this is referring to the fact that type theory is usually presented as a deductive system starting from nothing, where as set theory is usually presented as a theory in first-order logic. This just shows that this is comparing apples and oranges: type theory is a deductive system, set theory and category theory are not.

Answer (score 5):

First a technical point. You would have to define what an isomorphism between type theory and category theory is supposed to be using a meta theory if you would like to claim that such an isomorphism exists.

Second, you are partially right. The trinity between type theory, category theory and logic suggest that they are all inter-related. You can express any of those topics in term of the other.

The reason why you do not discard any of them is because they provide different viewpoints towards the same concept.

To give you an analogy, this is similar to the basic advantage of proof theory where you consider proof as mathematical objects, in the end if you have a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus and a proof that two triangles are similar, they both encode the information "true" but in a very different way. You will not supposedly, discard one for the other.

Now the different viewpoints are :

- Logic -> Proof theory. There is an emphasis in manipulating proof as mathematical objects in your deductive system.
- Type theory -> algorithms. There is an emphasis in manipulating algorithms which are just a collection of instructions.
- Category Theory -> algebra. Here the emphasis is on manipulating algebraic objects using algebraic rules.

It is best to get comfortable with these different viewpoint as any can provide you meaningful information about the other as the past has shown consistently.

Hope that helps !